# REGEX - How to get rid of quotation marks at the start and end of a string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Have a bunch of strings

```
"pipe 1/4" square"
"3" bar"
"3/16" spanner
2" nozzle
spare tyre
```

I want to get rid of `"` marks from the start of the string and the end of the string with RegEx. 
I've been trying on a [simulator](http://regexr.com/) with the aid of some [references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) but cannot seem to do it right.

**Q:** What is the RegEx that will do this with BASH?

Comment: Use this regex: `^(.*)"$`  The contents inside the parenthesis will be everything _except_ for the final quotation mark.  I will leave this as a comment because you never told us the programming language you are using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry - it was in bash - how would I use it with `$var` `echo $var | sed ^(.*)"$ ` very unfamiliar with the regex.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex to match double quotes which exists at the start and end of a line `^"|"$` and then replace the match with empty string.

Using sed.

```
sed 's/^"\|"$//g' <<<$var
```

Comment: How would I use it with $var echo $var | sed ^(.*)"$ very unfamiliar with the regex - any pointers to use in bash would very helpful

Comment: try `sed 's/^"\|"$//' <<<$var`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
echo $var | sed 's/^(.*)"$/\1/'
```

This will pass the variable `$var` into the `sed` command via the pipe `|` operator.  Sed will then substitute this input string with the group match in parenthesis.  This match is available in `sed` as `\1`.  So your input string, minus the final quotation mark, is what will actually be output by `echo`.

Comment: Please explain how your code addresses the OP's problem. Help others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
a="\"pipe 1/4\" square\""
a="${a/#\"/}" && a="${a/%\"/}"
echo "$a"
```

Output:

```
pipe 1/4" square
```

Explanation:

`${var/old/new}` replaces `old` with `new` in `$var`. 
A `#` before `old` makes it to match at the beginning of `$var`.
A `%` before `old` makes it to match at the end of `$var`.